# Halmos on domain and range of relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I am reading Halmos’s *Naive Set Theory*. He writes:

> If $R = X \times F$, then $\mbox{dom } R = X$ and $\mbox{ran } R = Y$.

I am confused by this. If $X \times Y = R$, wouldn’t $\mbox{dom } R = X$ and $\mbox{ran } R = Y$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe it's not just a typo?

Comment: I’m not sure, that’s why I’m asking:)

Comment: Let me ask in a different way: If you assume it's a typo, is there anything else on the page (or in the section) that would stop making sense?

Comment: He uses F again later in the section. However if I was to swap both F’s with Y it would make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found out there is a typo in the kindle edition of Naive Set Theory by Halmos. In this version https://books.google.com.au/books?id=x6cZBQ9qtgoC&pg=PA26&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false he has used Y not F.